# how does libtorch get tensor device type?

Tags: cpu, device, tensor, libtorch

Is there any method for libtorch to get the tensor or model device type.

Just like `xxx.device` in pytorch?

```
import torch
tensor = torch.rand(3,4)
print(tensor.device)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libtorch was designed to provide almost exactly the same features in C++ as in python, so when in doubt you can try :

```
#include <torch/torch.h>
torch::Tensor tensor = torch::rand({3,4});
std::cout << tensor.device() << std::endl;
```

Plot twist : it works \o/